# Accessing another user calendar using the O365 REST API from a single domain admin account

Tags: c#, .net, azure, office365

We are in the process now of adapting our internal company applications to Office 365. Both systems are  MVC projects. We are trying to use the O365 REST API directly. Need help on the following:

1. How to get an appointment from another person in our company O365 account using Domain Admin credentials? We can also consider adding visibility of the person's calendar to the admin account calendars list under "My Calendars" or "Other Calendars".
2. How to set an appointment inside another person calendar using the Super Admin account.

Basically what we want is to be able to perform operations using 1 account into other users calendars and using the REST API directly.

Will really appreciate assistance in this matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for your question!  Today, the Office 365 Calendar REST APIs only allow retrieving or updating calendar of the authenticated user.  We are really close to adding support for a service account that is granted access by an admin to all users in the tenant, and can retrieve and update calendars of users in the tenant without the user being present.  So, your scenario should be unblocked in a few weeks.  Stay tuned for an announcement on how to set up and use service accounts.

**[UPDATE]:** Alternately, you can use Exchange Web Services (EWS) SOAP APIs now to do this.  Please check out [how application impersonation works](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn722377(v=exchg.150).aspx) and here for [using .NET EWS Managed API for app impersonation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633680(v=exchg.80).aspx).  The client side APIs available are .NET [EWS Managed API](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-managed-api) and [EWS Java API](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api) in case you use one of these runtimes.

**[UPDATE]:** Support for service accounts for REST APIs is now available. Please see our [blog announcement](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2015/01/22/building-demon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow.aspx) for more details and let us know if you have any questions.  Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Can I use Exchange Online Services to do so?

Comment: Hi abarreiro, yes, you can use Exchange Web Services and I updated my answer with additional info.  Let me know if you have any questions.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi abarreiro, Service account support for REST API is now available. Please take a look at my updated answer for more info. Thanks.

Comment: Microsoft, please update the link in this post! It says "MSDN and TechNet blog sites have been retired, and blog content has been migrated and archived here."

Every documentation about this matter is just of pile of outdated microsoft links!